# firefoxアドオンの開発環境が構築できない

Tags: firefox

firefoxのアドオンを作成したいと思っています。
下記のサイトを参考にしているのですが、情報から少し時間がたっているせいか同じようにいきません。

https://dev.mozilla.jp/addon-sdk-docs/dev-guide/tutorials/installation.html
https://dev.mozilla.jp/addon-sdk-docs/dev-guide/tutorials/getting-started-with-cfx.html

cfx入門のページのcfx initまでは同じようにできているのですが、
cfx runコマンドを打つと

(C:\addon-sdk-1.17) C:\addon-sdk-1.17\bin\my-addon>cfx run
Using binary at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'.
Using profile at 'c:\users\ux21a\appdata\local\temp\tmps1leik.mozrunner'.
と表示され、firefoxが真白な状態で立ち上がります。

これはどこかにミスがあるということなのでしょうか？それとも情報が古いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

試してみましたが、おそらく情報が古いのではないかと思います。

> firefoxが真白な状態で立ち上がります。

こちらについては`cfx init`で作成される「main.js」に何も記述されていないので
真っ白になるのが正常だと思われます。

sdk配下の「examples」というディレクトリにいくつかサンプルが入っていますので、
それらを使用して`cfx run`を実行すると動きが確認できると思います。
※`cfx init`で作成したディレクトリに中身を移しても動きました。

「reddit-panel」
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

----- 追記 -----
英語サイトの方が新しいようなので、一応貼っておきます。
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials